# Why use if(!!obj){} in javascript instead of if(obj){}

Tags: javascript

I brow some code in javascript, found some code of function like that

```js
function isPromise(obj) {
  return !!obj && (typeof obj === 'object' || typeof obj === 'function') && typeof obj.then === 'function';
}
```

As what I say to the title, why this function use !!obj" ??

Comment: Agree, it looks pointless in your code (though a better test would always return a boolean)

Comment: For boolean operation they have used !!

Comment: You can absolutely avoid using `!!` because you're checking it with typeof. So, it's pointless to use.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar: Yes and no. `!!` is not necessary but the boolean check for `obj` is. Without it, `typeof null === 'object'` is `true`, and then `typeof null.then` will throw an error.

Comment: @FelixKling hmm, you're right. I din't think about null.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to "double bang" in JavaScript it is a force coercion  falsely or truthy to its `boolean` `true` or `false`

See this answer:
[What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)